# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://PojectName)

Tags: php, ajax

Here I tried to call `findoc.php` on button(docbutton) click which will send its value, and onclick button named hyperlinks from finddoc.php it should send back value to index.html to function `getPage(doctype,page)`

But i found value from docbutton was sent to `finddoc.php`, but from `finddoc.php` button hyperlinks call is throwing error

> Uncaught Reference Error : doctype is not defined on HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Here is my code:

```
<html>
            <head>
            <title>TCS Portal</title>

            <!----<script src="js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>---->
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
                    var xmlhttp=false;  
                    try{
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    catch(e)    {       
                        try{            
                            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch(e){
                            try{
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                            catch(e1){
                                xmlhttp=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return xmlhttp;
                }

                function getDoc(docType) { 

                var strURL="finddoc.php?doc_type="+docType;
              var req = getXMLHTTP();
              if (req) {
               req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                 // only if "OK"
                 if (req.status == 200) {      
                  document.getElementById('doc').innerHTML=req.responseText; 
                    //document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML='<button>'+'</button>';
                 } else {
                  alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);

                 }
                }    
               }   
               req.open("GET", strURL, true);
               req.send(null);
              }  
             }

            function getPage(docType,page) { 

                var strURL="finddoc.php?doc_type="+docType+"&page="+page;
              var req = getXMLHTTP();
              if (req) {
               req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                 // only if "OK"
                 if (req.status == 200) {      
                  document.getElementById('doc').innerHTML=req.responseText;    

                 } else {
                  alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);

                 }
                }    
               }   
               req.open("GET", strURL, true);
               req.send(null);
              }  
             }

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <button id="docbutton" onclick="getDoc(this.value)" value="mybutton"><span>mybutton</span></button>
            <div id="doc" align ="center">
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>

            --------------------------finddoc.php---------------------------------------


            <html>

            <body>
            <?php
            include('db_connect.php');
            //error_reporting(0);

            ?>


            <?php 
            $doc_type=$_GET['doc_type'];

            $limit = 14;  
            if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
            $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

            $sql="SELECT * FROM documents where doc_type = '$doc_type' LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            ?>

            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             ?>

             <ul>
             <li>
            <a class="content_a" href="<?=$row['doc_path'].$row['doc_name'] ?>"> <?=$row['doc_name'] ?></a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <?php 

            } ?>
            <?php  
            //$limit = 14;
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM documents where doc_type = '$doc_type'";  
            $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result);  
            $total_records = $row[0];  
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
            //$pagLink = "<div id='pagination'>";  
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  ?>
                   <button name="hyperlinks" onclick="getPage(<?=$doc_type?>,<?=$i?>)" value="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></button> 
            <?php
            };  
            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I wanted `getPage` function to be called with the sent parameters and send back response to `finddoc.php`

Comment: This code works fine - there is no type error.

Answer (score 0):

I also found there is an error Failed to load resource net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED throwing at

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```